# tar directory to send only modified blocks of files

Tags: rsync, tar, synchronization

Deep and complex directory structure can be modified: files can be moved (prefix changed) and simultaneously content of the files can be changed partially.

I want to decrease an amount of data to transmit over network.

`rsync` works with chunks of data of 4k size (if I remember correctly).

Can I use some kind of concatenation (`tar`-like) preserving meta information about file system structure and attributes, which places the file's content starting from offsets of multiple 4k bytes for each next file to enable `rsync` algorithm advantages?

The problem I want to solve is omission of `rsync`: it unable to detect if file content changed and file is moved at the same time between synchronizations to use matching blocks of destination files to reduce data transfer.

Comment: Have a look at `inosync`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your suggestion in a comment (which should really be in your question), this seems to be what you want

```
cd /path/to/directory
tar cf /var/tmp/directory.tar .
rsync -azv /var/tmp/directory.tar remote:/var/tmp/directory.tar
ssh remote 'cd /path/to/destination && tar xf /var/tmp/directory.tar'
```

You need enough space to store `directory.tar` on both sides.

---

I've been asked whether this apparently trivial solution can work in the situation where a small amount, such as a single byte, is added (or removed) from the beginning of the tar file.

Hopefully this sample will illustrate how good `rsync` is at handling such situations. It works best if you have an equivalence (certificate key) login for the remote server so that no time is spent entering a password.

```
# Generate some data
dd iflag=fullblock bs=1M count=200 </dev/urandom >200M.dat

# See how long it takes to transfer
time rsync -av 200M.dat remote:

# See how long it takes to transfer "nothing"
time rsync -av 200M.dat remote:

# Generate one byte of data and prepend it to another data file
dd bs=1 count=1 </dev/urandom >1b.dat
cat 1b.dat 200M.dat >200M1b.dat

# Copy the new file across to the original target
time rsync -av 200M1b.dat remote:200M.dat

# Clean up
rm 1b.dat 200M.dat 200M1b.dat
ssh remote rm 200M.dat
```

If the algorithm can handle the single byte inserted at the beginning of the data stream the transfer should take but a few moments. If it can't you would expect the transfer time to be broadly similar to the first.

Comment: This is not the solution. Imagine, that some single file in the beginning of the tar archive has size 0 byte and after update became of size 1 byte. 4k-blocks related to all the next files in a tar archive layout now cannot be recognized by `rsync` as identical to counterparts on remote side even if they are not changed at all. This is because of different offset.

Comment: Do you really think, that answer can be so trivial?

Comment: @Orient rsyncs algorithm is not dependent on the data’s position in the file, iirc. It chops the source into chunks, checks wether this chunk exists in the target file. The algorithm would be rather useless if a one byte offset would cause the whole file to be retransferred.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I'll read the article about rolling checksum. But intuitively it seems, that it is not possible, what you say.

Comment: @Orient I have added a proof of concept to my answer for you. See what you think.

Comment: @Orient: well, then I suggest you write a paper to further the discussion based on facts.

Comment: Seems it works.

Comment: I tested it locally on real data using `rsync --archive --no-whole-file --stats --verbose --verbose --info=progress2 --checksum 2.tar 3.tar` gives big speedup `total: matches=159205  hash_hits=222154  false_alarms=22 data=114688`.

Comment: Triple disk usage overhead implied =(.

Comment: @Orient you may find that reverting to the "obvious" `rsync` solution works well enough for you, possibly with the `--fuzzy --fuzzy` flags. It depends on how many files get moved around into different folders and how large they are.

Comment: @roaima `man rsync` for version I have tells, that this heuristic only works for simple cases: for renaming files w/o changing prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another suggestion for you. The [`hrsync` tool](https://github.com/dparoli/hrsync), which I've found on GitHub, appears to be pretty good at maintaining a memory of files when you rename them or move them between directories of a source tree.

- It can track moves and edits to files within the source tree
- It is a shell script and does not require administrative privileges to install on the source system, although putting it into `/usr/local/bin` does have advantages
- It requires both local and remote systems to have a filesystem capable of handling hard links
- It is not able to track changes to a file where that file is renamed and *replaced* (i.e. deleted and then recreated, rather than edited in place)

Example

```
hrsync /path/to/directory/ remote:/path/to/destination/
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using `bash` and command-line utilities only. It is possible to optimize the solution: sort files by size in ascending order and place as many small files as possible to every chunk (knapsack problem here =), but it would be overengineering):

`pack.bash`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -e

[[ -d "$1" ]]
[[ -d "$( dirname '$2' )" ]]

BLOB="$2.blob"
FSIZES="$2.sizes"
OFFSET=0

shopt -s globstar
for f in "$1"/* "$1"/**/*
do
    if [[ -f "$f" ]]
    then
        SIZE=$( stat -c %s "$f" )
        echo "$SIZE" >> "$FSIZES"
        COUNT=$(( ($SIZE + 4096 - 1) / 4096 ))
        dd if="$f" of="$BLOB" bs=4096 seek=$OFFSET count=$COUNT conv=notrunc
        OFFSET=$(( $COUNT + $OFFSET ))
    fi
done

cp --recursive --archive --attributes-only "$1" "$2.dir"
XZ_OPT="-9e --threads=$(( $( nproc ) + 1 ))" tar cpJf "$2.tar.xz" -C "$2.dir" .
rm --recursive "$2.dir"
```

`unpack.bash`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -e

BLOB="$2.blob"
FSIZES="$2.sizes"

[[ -f "$BLOB" ]]
[[ -f "$FSIZES" ]]

mkdir --parents "$1"
[[ ! "$( ls -A '$1' )" ]]

tar xpJf "$2.tar.xz" -C "$1"

SIZES=($( < "$FSIZES" ))

i=0
OFFSET=0
shopt -s globstar
for f in "$1"/* "$1"/**/*
do
    if [[ -f "$f" ]]
    then
        SIZE=${SIZES[i]}
        dd if="$BLOB" of="$f" bs=4096 skip=$OFFSET count=$SIZE iflag=count_bytes
        OFFSET=$(( $OFFSET + ($SIZE + 4096 - 1) / 4096 ))
        i=$(( $i + 1 ))
    fi
done
```